# Use integers of exact sizes c++

Tags: c++, types

I know that this question has been asked a lot, but i have never seen an appropriate answer that will suit my needs. I am writing a compiler and interpreter for fun in c++, and in order to write them, i need to be sure that the types i am using are 8 bit, 32 bit, 64  bit, etc...  I have found , but i have been warned that it may not work on all platforms.  I have also heard that some platforms do not support integers of these sizes, but it must be possible, because java manages to achieve this.  Unfortunately java source code is not available.

Comment: Java compiled code does not work on "all platforms". It works on JVM platform, which is independent from the computer architecture. So, it is not that "java manages to achieve this" but that it does not even try to do that.

Comment: but java is available on all major platforms, and its types are always the same size.

Comment: But internally the JVM may be using an int64 for "java integer" on one platform, an int32 in another.

Comment: "Unfortunately java source code is not available." eh, huh, openjdk?

Comment: @PlasmaHH The key word with regards to Java availability is "major".  PC's and the mainline Unix machines do have the specified sizes.  Some mainframes and embedded processors don't.  And Java made a conscious decision when it was designed _not_ to support them.  C and C++ traditionally do support them.

Comment: In theory, on platfroms without a 64 bit integer, you can fake it with two 32 bit ints and manual carry.  On platforms without 8 bit ints, you can fake it with bit operations to extract it from larger blocks, and you can fake 1 byte addressing by not using native pointers.  But I doubt it is worth it to go that far.  You are takimg baby steps, and worrying about how you will walk on lava at the bottom of the ocean.  Stop borrowing trouble.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I never said something else, I was just commenting on the statement that there is no java source code available.

Comment: @SJuan76 No.  In Java, an `int` is _always_ 32 bits 2's complement.  If the hardware doesn't support this (and some don't), then the JVM must emulate it (with enormous runtime costs) or not support the platform.

Comment: @JamesKanze that's what I meant that the JVM may be using an "int64" in a platform, the Java program only sees the 32 bit integer but does not know the types the processor handles because the JVM hides it. My comment was in line with Yakk's.

Comment: @SJuan76 OK.  The `int` type in JVM corresponds to `int32_t` in C++.  Always.  But how the implementation of a JVM achieves this goal is its problem.  (From a practical point of view, of course, Java won't run on a machine which doesn't have hardware support for `int32_t`.  The JVM _can_ emulate it, but the performance hit would be enough to make the implementation unusable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to ensure that the types you use are exactly 32
bit, etc.  This is certainly unnecessary in a compiler or an
interpreter.  (You might want `int_least32_t`, depending.  But
usually, you'll want to use `int` everywhere, so that the compiler
will work everywhere---although some programs might be too large
for it on a 16 bit machine.)

As for portability: if you're doing this for fun, the only
platform you need to worry about is a PC.  But even if you want
to extend to the common Unix platforms, you'll find that types
like `int32_t` are available there as well.  About the only
place you won't find them is on some exotic mainframes and some
embedded systems.  (Neither of which would be supported by Java,
either.)

Answer (score 7):

The [`<stdint.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) ( `<cstdint>` on c++) header contains `typedef`s that obey a specific size:

```
int8_t x;
int16_t y;
int32_t z;
```

If the typedef doesn't exist then the platform doesn't support it. To check it you have some available macros like `INT16_MIN` `INT16_MAX` that defines the minimum and maximum value of a specified integer so that you can see it for yourself.

Comment: Those types are optional, if the implementation can not provide them, they need not be there.

Comment: Great, but please don't link to that website.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I get your point but I didn't mind when talking about such a standard issue with no interpretation issues ;)

Comment: @EricFinn: http://kera.name/articles/2013/02/cplusplus-com-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/

Comment: @Jack: Okay fair enough. I just try to remove references to it because seeing it makes newbies think that there is an "official" (and therefore canonical) C++ reference called cplusplus.com, which couldn't be further from the truth.

Answer (score 2):

Exact size types are defined by C99 standard in `stdint.h` header file (have a look [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/stdint.h.html)). You simply need a C99-compatible compiler, like modern GCC and Clang. In C++, use `cstdint` instead.

Besides, the OpenJDK source code *is* publicly released, you can download or browse it from the links provided [on the project page](http://openjdk.java.net/) and study it.

EDIT: there is a small number of platforms (exotic, embedded or very very old) that do not declare or support these types. On those, it is not possible to get exact size types, still you can target most if not any currently-used home/enterprise processors without having to worry.

Comment: Please use `cstdint` in C++.

Comment: This doesn't address his question: what to do when the exact size types aren't available.  They _aren't_ supported on every platform.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11 has been released, there are [Fixed width integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) that give you types at least as big as you want.

Comment: but if the type sizes change, then a file compiled on one system will be incompayible with another

Comment: @Popgalop A file compiled on one system generally isn't compatible with one compiled on another.  Independently of the sizes.

Comment: The fixed width integer types aren't guaranteed to be present.  (The OP was apparently  aware of `<stdint.h>`, and the fact that the exact width types weren't available on some architectures.)